# AWS cli elasticbeanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, command-line-interface

How does one create an rds db along with the aws cli for elastic beanstalk?

```
aws elasticbeanstalk create-environment
```

I was able to make the command create a new elastic beanstalk environment but it did not create the rds db for me. Is there something I must configure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When calling the `create-environment` endpoint, you can also specify the option `--option-settings` as shown in [the documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elasticbeanstalk/create-environment.html).

All of the Option Settings can be found [on this page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options.html). Specifically, look for the `aws:rds:dbinstance` section to see the RDS specific ones.

An example JSON config might look like this:

```
[
    {
        "Namespace": "aws:rds:dbinstance",
        "OptionName": "DBName",
        "Value": "my-database"
    },
    {
        "Namespace": "aws:rds:dbinstance",
        "OptionName": "Engine",
        "Value": "mysql"
    },
    {
        "Namespace": "aws:rds:dbinstance",
        "OptionName": "MasterUsername",
        "Value": "user"
    },
    {
        "Namespace": "aws:rds:dbinstance",
        "OptionName": "MasterUserPassword",
        "Value": "hunter2"
    },
    {
        "Namespace": "aws:rds:dbinstance",
        "OptionName": "DBInstanceClass",
        "Value": "db.m1.small"
    }
    // ...
]
```

Comment: Thanks, yes I do have a options file and I have DBEngine, DBDeletionPolicy, DBPassword, and MultiAZDatabase defined in the file. Am I required to also have the db name, and username and class? They seem to be optional according to the documentation.

Comment: So just setting these options doesn't work for me.Also it looks like the `OptionName`s are out of date now.

Comment: @ranman, my coworker informed me that this doesn't handle actually creating the database shortly after I answered this ;) I was grateful for that as I'm new to the team.